# testing normality for a data set

Tags: r, statistics

I have one column with density data values for 40 samples and another column with sample number; and I want to test if there is a difference in density (p<0.05). would I be able to use Kruskal wallis or ANOVA for this data set?

Also, whenever I use tapply function to test the normality of this data it says:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : sample size must be between 3 and 5000.

All my data values are below 1 as it is density and I have one type of sample (there are no different categories), so how would I test the normality and what statistical test should I do for this type of data?

Comment: Could we please have a [mcve]? I think there are approximately three different questions here, some of which belong on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) instead, e.g. (1) How do I run a Kruskal-Wallis test and/or one-way ANOVA on my data? (2) What test should I use? (3) Why doesn't the Shapiro test work (and what can I do about it)? Can you focus your question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using shapiro test which in R doesn't work for sample with more than 5000 element.

As mentioned in the comments of this post and after correction by Stephane:

```
library(nortest)
lillie.test(test_vector)
```

And If you have replicates for your sample, and depending on the results of the normality test, I guess yes, ANOVA or KW look good

I hope it helped

Comment: Using the two-samples Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with a simulated sample is not correct practice.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, I do it quite often tho. What would you propose then? I modified then to use the "model" given by documentation on ks.test()

Comment: (1/2) This is not correct as well. This time you are doing a one-sample Kolmogorov test, comparing the distribution of the sample to the normal distribution with mean the sample mean and standard deviation the sample standard deviation. The one-sample Kolmogorov test is used to compare the distribution of a sample to a theoretical distribution with known parameters. Here you take for the parameters of the theoretical distribution some estimates based on the sample. When you do that, you have to take into account the uncertainty about the parameters.

Comment: (2/2) Then this is not a correct usage of the Kolmogorov test. You have to use the *Lilliefors* test instead.

Comment: Ok, very good to know, then lillie.test() from nortest package should do for the problem, thanks for you correction!